# Nested Eager Loading not work when upgrade to laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, loading, eager

I created 3 models are Exams, Questions and Answers. I use nested eager loading to load all questions and answers of specific exams.

My function is:

```
public function allBy($examId)
{
    return \Exam::with('questions.answers')->get();
}
```

It works in Laravel 5.1. Today, I upgrade my project to Laravel 5.2 by creating new project and move files to it. However, when running above function, it quit program suddenly. In client side's console window (Chrome), it displays error with status 500 (Internal Server Error).

I try to use "try...catch" but it does not go to *catch*. It still quit when do get() function. I don't know where is the problem.

I also try to make simple eager loading:

```
return \Exam::with('questions')->get();
```

It works in laravel 5.2.

Comment: Check log file for information about what is causing the error

Comment: In storage\logs\laravel.log, I don't see any information logged when issue happens.

Comment: Enable the debugging mode by going into `config/app.php`, and setting `'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', true),`. Then show us the error that appears on the page.

Comment: It displays: FatalErrorException in Container.php line 700:
Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!

Comment: FYI, when I deep debug into Laravel framework, I recognize it quits at answers() function in my Question Model. In this function, I have only one code row: return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Answer' which used to define eloquent relationship.

Comment: I try create new project again and add dependence alternately. It works (load nested eagger loading success) until I add DebugBar (barryvdh/laravel-debugbar ver 2.1). After I disable DebugBar, It work again. What do DebugBar make issue?

Comment: I make more test for finding reason. Test 1 with enable DebugBar and use middleware "web" and "auth", it does not work. Test 2 with enable DebugBar and use only middleware "web", it works.

Comment: I search error nesting level of '100' reached. Some one suggested change  xdebug.max_nesting_level =200. I try to change. And it works.